# Evolutionary Algorithm without an objective function

Tags: c++, matlab, mathematical-optimization, evolutionary-algorithm

I'm currently trying to find good parameters for my program (about 16 parameters and execution of the program takes about a minute). Evolutionary algorithms seemed like a nice idea and I wanted to see how they perform.

Unfortunately I don't have a good fitness function because the variance of my objective function is very high (I can not run it often enough without waiting until 2016). I can, however, compute which set of parameters is better (test two configurations against each other). Do you know if there are evolutionary algorithms that only use that information? Are there other optimization techniques more suitable? For this project I'm using C++ and MATLAB.

// Update: Thank you very much for the answers. Both look promising but I will need a few days to evaluate them. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Evolutionary algorithms may be what you're looking to use, but keep in mind that they're often used as metaheuristic optimization algorithm. I don't necessarily understand the nature of what you're trying to do, but with so many parameters, you could try a Naive Bayes or BayesNet approach.

Comment: I don't think BayesNet would be the right approach. You can see my program as a mathematical function which I want to optimize. Only that there is a lot of noise on top of it. So if I use the objective value directly I think I might get stuck in the tiny holes generated by the noise...

Comment: Can't you use a more classical approach to optimise, e.g. conjugate gradient?

Comment: No I can't because I don't have any idea of what the gradient looks like (is it a polynomial, log,...), there are multiple optima (which I get stuck on), the noise makes an estimation of the gradient unreliable and estimating the gradient of a 16d function takes a lot of function evaluations which again takes a long time. The only thing that was working somewhat was a cross entropy search with a multinomial function see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-entropy_method

Comment: In Expectation-Maximization, one of the things we used to was to stop iterating long before reaching full convergence: that was a way to try and converge toward the signal but not toward the noise. I wonder if something similar could be applied here :-/

Comment: So I think stopping early makes sense and using a big population size also solves the problem of the local optima. But I have a nice way to compare ParamA with ParamB so I really would like to use that instead of a single objective function. Also EM doesn't work here because as far as I know there are a lot of dependencies between the parameters and additionally I don't have a gradient (see previous comment) which means EM will be super slow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your pairwise test gives a proper total ordering, i.e. if a >= b, and b >= c implies a >= c, and [some other conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) . Then maybe you can construct a ranking objective on the fly, and use [CMA-ES](https://www.lri.fr/~hansen/cmaesintro.html) to optimize it. CMA-ES is an evolutionary algorithm and is invariant to order preserving transformation of function value, and angle-preserving transformation of inputs. Furthermore because it's a second order method, its convergence is very fast comparing to other derivative-free search heuristics, especially in higher dimensional problems where random search like genetic algorithms take forever.

Comment: Okay so I think in order to use CMA-ES with my ranking I have to record the complete order of all parameter evaluations. Which means whenever I get a new parameter I have to do a binary search to find my place in the ordering, is that what you were implying? This could take a long time (maybe a factor 10 for 1000 evaluations) but it may be worth it. If you have a better/faster way, please let me know.

Comment: @user667804 that is one possibility, and it is closer to what I had in mind originally. But now looking at the pseudo code on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMA-ES, I think you don't need global ranking, but just per-batch ranking when you sample in each iteration. This is usually a small fixed set, for size 10 for example.

Answer (score 2):

If you can compare solutions in a pairwise fashion then some sort of [tournament selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_selection) approach might be good. The Wikipedia article describes using it for a genetic algorithm but it is easily applied to an evolutionary algorithm. What you do is repeatedly select a small set of solutions from the population and have a tournament among them. For simplicity the tournament size could be a power of 2. If it was 8 then pair those 8 up at random and compare them, selecting 4 winners. Pair those up and select 2 winners. In a final round -- select an overall tournament winner. This solution can then be mutated 1 or more times to provide member(s) for the next generation.